# c++ system() "the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: python, c++, windows

I'm trying to run a Python script in C++ using `system()`:

```cpp
system("\"python\" \"E:\\python\\main.py\"");
```

But I get an error in the console:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

When I run the same command in cmd, it works. These also work:

```cpp
system("python \"E:\\python\\main.py\"");
system("\"python\" E:\\python\\main.py");
```

But I need it to contain quotes because paths may contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, `system()` runs the specified command using `cmd.exe /C <command>`.  Per `cmd`'s documentation:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters, where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving any text after the last quote character.

All three of your examples are falling into #2, where:

- `system("\"python\" \"E:\\python\\main.py\"");`

  executes: `python" "E:\python\main.py` - FAILS
- `system("python \"E:\\python\\main.py\"");`

  executes: `python "E:\python\main.py"` - OK
- `system("\"python\" E:\\python\\main.py");`

  executes: `python E:\python\main.py` - OK

So, to avoid problems, you need to wrap the entire command string with an extra set of quotes, eg:

```cpp
system("\"\"python\" \"E:\\python\\main.py\"\"");
```

Which executes: `"python" "E:\python\main.py"`, as expected.

That being said, a better option in this situation is to not go through `cmd.exe` at all. Use `CreateProcessA()` instead to run `python.exe` directly, eg:

```
char cmdLine[] = "\"python\" \"E:\\python\\main.py\"";

STARTUPINFOA si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
// set other fields as desired...

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    // success...
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
else
{
    // failed...
}
```

Of course, an even better option is to not run `python.exe` at all.  There are plenty of 3rd party libraries available that can run Python script for you.  See [Embed a Python interpreter in a (Windows) C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596013/) for some ideas.